# Find an increasing sequence of rationals that converges to $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers, pi

I am not sure how to construct a sequence that would convey convergence to $\pi$.

Except maybe $a_n=\{\pi + 1/n\}$ but the terms would not be rational.

Looking for an adequate way to show to satisfy the three conditions.

Comment: $$\{3,3.1,3.14,3.141,\ldots\}$$

Comment: This is a convention that assumes it would eventually converge to pi?

Comment: $\{2\tan^{-1} n\}$

Comment: Well you will need to write it in a more formal way then @graydad did, but it's exactly the right sequence. There is no convention in play. Depending on exactly which version of the reals you are using this might even be one of the elements of the equivalence class which **is** $\pi$.

Comment: @cgo the termes of the $\tan^{-1}$ are not rational

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80 or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut the sequence needs to be monotone increasing

Comment: @marwalix Take an obvious subsequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build on my comment, there are probably a few ways to define that sequence. One "lazy" way to do it is to recognize that $\pi$ as an irrational has the property that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can find the $n^{th}$ decimal in $\pi$'s decimal expansion. So for $b_i \in \{0,1,\ldots,8,9\}$ we can write $$\pi = b_0.b_1b_2b_3b_4\ldots b_{k-1}b_kb_{k+1}\ldots$$ where obviously $b_0 = 3, b_1 = 1$, etc. Now define $a_n = b_0.b_1\ldots b_n$ to get the sequence $$\{3,3.1,3.14,\ldots \}$$ Along with this you may also need to prove that $a_k \leq a_{k+1}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ but that should be pretty easy if you just consider $a_{k+1}-a_{k}$.

Comment: There's a cute way to write this sequence using the floor function: $b_n = 10^{-n} \lfloor 10^n \pi \rfloor$.

Comment: @Vectornaut yeh that is pretty adorable; I knew it was something like that but kept psyching myself out that I had it written wrong.

Answer (score 12):

[Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) tells us:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac{\pi}4=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}\dots$$

Group the terms by two, the difference is positive, so there is an obvious increasing sequence of rationals that converges to $\pi$:

$$4\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)+4\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}\right)+\dots$$

Or more formally

$$S_n=4\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{4k+1}-\frac{1}{4k+3}\right)=8\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$$

Then $S_n$ is obviously rational and increasing, and $S_n\to\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

The sequence in [graydad's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1469928/16063) can be written in terms of the floor function as
$$n \mapsto 10^{-n} \lfloor 10^n \pi \rfloor.$$
This suggests some cute generalizations. Instead of the decimal expansion for $\pi$, we can use the expansion in any base $q$:
$$n \mapsto q^{-n} \lfloor q^n \pi \rfloor$$
converges to $\pi$ for any whole number $q \ge 2$. In fact,
$$n \mapsto a_n^{-1} \lfloor a_n \pi \rfloor$$
converges to $\pi$ for any increasing sequence $n \mapsto a_n$ of natural numbers!

Answer (score 2):

Let $n_0:=\lfloor\pi\rfloor$ and define inductively $$n_{k+1}:=\left\lfloor10^{k+1}\left(\pi-\sum_{i=0}^k\dfrac{n_i}{10^i}\right)\right\rfloor.$$ Then $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^m\dfrac{n_k}{10^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{n_k}{10^k}=\pi.$$