# True rational approximation of Pi

Tags: number-theory

Is there an approximation of $\pi$ expressed as a series of rational numbers?

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{p(n)}{q(n)}}=\pi $$

where $p(n)$ and $q(n)$ are whole numbers as known functions of $n=1,2,3,$ ...

I couldn't find any without a square root or some other irrational element.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469915/find-an-increasing-sequence-of-rationals-that-converges-to-pi/1469940#1469940 If you need explicit formulas for $p(n)$ and $q(n)$, take $p(n)=(4n+3)!S_n$ and $q_n=(4n+3)!$.

Comment: Some of [these classical formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Other_classical_formulae) look like they would give you a series of rational numbers, specifically the "Newton / Euler convergence transformation" and the Chudnovsky formula.

Comment: @Rahul Doesn't the latter contain a square root?

Comment: Ah right, didn't notice the $3/2$ in the exponent, my bad.

Comment: an article that may be of interest to you.  
https://www.quantamagazine.org/new-proof-settles-how-to-approximate-numbers-like-pi-20190814/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use the Wallis product: $$\pi=2\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}\approx2\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{2^{n+1}n!^2}{(2n+1)(\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1))^2}=\frac{2^{3n+1}n!^4}{(2n)!(2n+1)!}.$$